# update function showed for me an error in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my code have an error in update part, it shows for me this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( reqdate= '2012-12-17',lat1= '26.18355762868919',long1= '50.30387832641602',lat' at line 1

and this is my code about update:

```
if(mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
$datex = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))+36000;
$time = date('H:i:s', $datex);
$date=date('Y-m-d', $datex);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sensorusers  WHERE uid='$uid'");

mysql_query("UPDATE requests SET ( reqdate= '$date',lat1= '$lat1',long1= '$lng1',lat2= '$lat2',long2='$lng2',lat3='$lat3',long3='$lng3',lat4='$lat4',long4='$lng4',inout='$type',time='$time') WHERE  sid= '$drivers'") or die(mysql_error());

$Alpha  = @mysql_query($query2,$db); //Execute Query

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the parenthesis and surely it will execute, eg

```
UPDATE requests 
SET   reqdate = '$date',
      lat1    = '$lat1',
      long1   = '$lng1',
      lat2    ='$lat2', 
      long2   = '$lng2', 
      lat3    = '$lat3',
      long3   = '$lng3',
      lat4    = '$lat4',
      long4   = '$lng4',
      `inout` = '$type',    // << RESERVED KEYWORD
      time    = '$time' 
WHERE  sid    = '$drivers'
```

`INOUT` is a **[RESERVED KEYWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**. You should escape it using backtick.

be warned that this code is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to learn  how to prevent from it,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: i removed ( ) but it stills give me the same error

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: this is the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inout='In',time='10:59:02') WHERE sid= '20080699-bedoor'' at line 1

Comment: that is now the new error. not the same with the previous error. `INOUT`is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html),you should escape it. see my updated answer.

Comment: hmm , i used the same name 'inout' in another query where i was inserted the data not update the data and it works fine

Comment: yes, but maybe you have escaped it using backtick.

Comment: i changed to inout1.. it gives me the same errrrrrror :( i will cry now

Comment: what error are you getting now? always post the error message please.

Comment: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE sid= '20080699-bedoor'' at line 1

Comment: remove the closing parenthesis, can you show the query you are executing?

Comment: waaw its worked! i forgot to remove the closed ) .. itttttsss worked!!! thank u very much! and i added also  `` for each column

Answer (score 0):

#### Syntax Error

Remove the `(` and `)` in your SQL.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE requests SET `reqdate` = '$date',lat1= '$lat1',long1= '$lng1',lat2= '$lat2',long2='$lng2',lat3='$lat3',long3='$lng3',lat4='$lat4',long4='$lng4',inout='$type',time='$time' WHERE  sid= '$drivers'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, consider using `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: i tried to remove them ,the same error showed for me :( .. how i can use the function that u determined?

Comment: BTW, you need to escape the column names using a backslash (`). Because, a few names seems to be reserved names.

Comment: Do u mean to put `` for each column?

Comment: Yeah! I meant that. :) At least for the `inout` field...